# Selenium html.text returning incomplete results

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

My problem is simple. The url below is for a linkedin page that contains 25 jobs. The code seems to be working but I'm surprised that it is returning some of the jobs but not all of the jobs displayed on the page. Why is it returning only half of the results? so can anyone provide some suggestions as I'm new to this? I've heard about requests but I want to do it using Selenium only. I'm grateful for any help! Thanks.

here's the url

```
url = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?f_TP=1&keywords=forecast&location=Toronto%2C%20Canada%20Area&locationId=ca%3A4876&sortBy=DD&start=0"
```

Here's my code:

```
body_html = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body")

print(body_html.text)
```

Comment: I just tried your code and all 25 jobs that show up on the page are showing up in the print.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm always getting 7 results out of the 25...can you share your code please? perhaps I missed something?

I need to get the text on the page..when I print(body_html) it gives an enormous amount of scripted code that is very hard to extract anything from. When I print(body_html.text) it gives me exactly what I want (as if I've manually copied the text on the page) but with only 7 results. Thanks